# Returning Subclass instead of superclass F#

Tags: c#, inheritance, f#

In C# we can do this:

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var animalCell = (AnimalCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (animalCellId, indexPath);

    var animal = animals [indexPath.Row];

    animalCell.Image = animal.Image;

    return animalCell;
}
```

where `AnimalCell` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`.

In `F#` I have defined my `AnimalCell` like this:

```
[<Register ("AnimalCell")>]
type AnimalCell (handle: IntPtr) = 
    inherit UICollectionViewCell (handle)
```

now I am implementing the same function:

```
override x.GetCell(collectionView : UICollectionView, indexPath : NSIndexPath) =
    let animalCell = (collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(new NSString("ChatCell"),indexPath)) :?> AnimalCell

    let animal = animals.[indexPath.Row]

    animalCell
```

This produces an error: `Error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'UICollectionViewCell'    but here has type    'AnimalCell' (FS0001)`

I can fix this by doing:

```
animalCell :> UICollectionViewCell
```

but why is this necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's necessary because unlike C#, F# does not automatic conversions (except in [some specific situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791480/why-upcast-is-not-necessary-in-this-let-bound-function/26791603#26791603)).

So there's less magic and more explicit conversions.